# Adjust jQuery code to show/hide div in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, html

I'm moving my site from HTML/CSS into CodeIgniter. Have some experience with PHP, but not much with jQuery.

The jQuery script I was using to `.show()`/`.hide()` `<div>`s worked fine with HTML pages, but doesn't work in CodeIgniter. I know what the script does (and I have attempted a few hours worth of modifications), but can't get it to function properly in CodeIgniter.

Here's what's happening: When I click on the `<a href="">` link, a new page opens, instead of opening the view into the `<div>`. Because of CodeIgniter's controllers, I'm not actually opening the page. I think this is where the difficulty is, but am not sure.

On the CodeIgniter side: I’ve already autoloaded the JavaScript library, and I am calling the script in the header. Here’s the jQuery code (HTML below):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var hash = [removed].hash.substr(1);  
    var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){  
        var href = $(this).attr('href');  
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){  
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)  
        }  
    });  

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){  

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';  
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();  
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
    [removed].hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);  
    function loadContent() {  
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $('#content).show('normal',hideLoader());  
    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
    }  
    return false;  

    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```html
<div id="leftcol">

<div id="usermenu">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/option1">Option 1</a></li><br />
<li><a href="/option2">Option 2</a></li><br />
<li><a href="/option2">Messages</a></li><br />
</ul>
</div>
</div>


<div id="content">

</div>

<div id="rightcol"

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you make sure your JS code is valid, try to put the [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method, to prevent browser from following the anchor link.

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a great tool for checking your JS scripts.

Comment: I read the link you provided; this looks like it might do the trick. Can I integrate this jquery snippet into my current code, or do I need a separate function? Don't know enough jquery to just append it.

Comment: Okay, saw your edit and will give it a try; will upvote your answer if it works.

Comment: Just insert it as the first line of the bind function... But what confuses me is how it was working earlier (when it was HTML) and now it won't (provided you copied the JS code). Again, make sure you verify your code since one mistake, one missing quote might break it all.

Comment: Thanks again. Okay, added in prevDef; still not working. Haven't changed the jquery code since adding it to the HTML page initially. It was working, so I left it alone. I'm going to recreate it in HTML, be sure it works again and try again in CI.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you post that page somewhere so I can see it? Try http://jsfiddle.net/ (I only need HTML, not PHP)

Comment: Checked the HTML version; it works fine. Here it is in jsfiddle (includes jquery). It's an early version of the code - http://jsfiddle.net/9qLrk/

Comment: Then there must be an error in your new code... Try putting alerts or console logs so you can see if the script executes at all.

Comment: Found a hidden error in the script code. Works perfectly now. I selected your answer, since you advised me to check the code again. Apologies for the trouble. When looking at things long enough, it's easy to miss minor things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied and pasted your code, then you might have a missing quotation mark here:

```
 function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content).show('normal',hideLoader());  
               ^
               |
 --------------+
```

And in `loadContent` and `showNewContent` functions, you should just give the callback function as parameters. You should not call them:

```
function loadContent() {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)  
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I made the correction; it's still not working.

Comment: Again, appreciate the comments. It's still not working. When I click the <a href> link, the browser opens a new page, instead of hiding/showing the view in the #content div.